# How to construct regex for time and numbers

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx that can handle an integer between 1 - 999 or time MM:SS from 00:00 to 59:59. This was my attempt `^?((\d{1,3})|((([0-9])|([0-5][0-9])):(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9]))))$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that:

```
(([0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])|\d{1,3})
```

(or that if you also need to match things like 0:17 or 17:2 or 3:8):

```
((([0-5][0-9]|[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])|[0-9])|\d{1,3})
```

You need to be aware that when you are matching regexes you are creating a very "simple" parser that *consumes characters from **left to right***.